# pivot table calculated field on counted column and summed column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a pivot table, data grouped by year in a Date field.
In the pivot there's a counted field (total) and a summed field (cat1, is 1 when it applies). I would like to get a percentage cat1 of total in a calculated field.

I've included an Excel file with a simple example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQyZLfmPuzPUDA3SDVSb2s4eDg/view?usp=sharing)

Have searched, couldn´t find it. Thanks in advance.

Jan-Willem

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this sollution:
I've added a column that calculates the percentage of one data row which is eather 100 or 0 percent. I use this column in the pivot table as an average. Bingo!

[Example of solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwQyZLfmPuzPanVDWk9va2JmMkE)

Maybe it helps someone else out.